# What should our site be called? / What should our domain name be?

Tags: discussion, site-name, domain-name

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/489/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

### Note:

We are closing this domain naming thread. It is asking the *entirely* wrong question. See this blog post for details: [Domain Names: Wrong Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

We're going to keep the name stats.stackexchange.com. But we WILL be setting up redirects from the more "popular" domains names (e.g. seasonedadvice.com to cooking.stackexchange.com, basicallymoney.com to money.stackexchange.com, and others as we go through the list).

New question: "**Write and Elevator Pitch / Tagline!**"

[**Click here to contribute ideas and vote.**](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/489/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

*[original message text below]*

---

Continuing with my previous question taken directly from the [7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/), here's another. What should we call our site (and linked to that what should our domain name be)?

[Blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/) about choosing domain.

## First round ended; the second will be announced soon.

[Here is a discussion about how the second round should look](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357/how-to-make-second-round-of-voting-for-the-site-name).

There are still new proposals comming! To see them click "newest" tab below: [image]

Comment: Just to emphasize one of my overarching views on the name: the site should be about "data analysis", and that should include all aspects of statistics (yes, including both bayesian and frequentist), visualization, machine learning/data mining, "data science", etc.  The title should include all these camps.

Answer (score 15):

## StatsOverflow.com

Comment: Familiar, but wouldn't it be better to have a name that's unique to our endeavour?  StackOverflow is a specific computer-science related concept.

Comment: @Shane That is indeed a good point. I just liked the familiarity the name generates with stackoverflow, the same way mathoverflow.net does.

Comment: @Tony That's why I think it should be something fitting into a S*[O*] scheme but still making sense.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything, unlike "StackOverflow". It will be harder to sell to people who aren't familiar with the SO site.

Comment: I like it. The "overflow" connotation has not hurt mathoverflow at all, and it is becoming a meme...i.e. people will understand what type of site it is immediately.

Comment: I just looked at some of the other SE sites, and I didn't see another one going for blahoverflow.com.  I agree with @Rob that this has a specific meaning for stackoverflow, and the SO team even chose different names for superuser and serverfault that were more relevant.

Comment: Although closely related, it attempts to borrow too much from it's successful progenitor. Although, arguably, many questions will be asked and answered that reflect the use of software for statistical analysis.

Comment: @Brandon Stack overflow is rather not the most hurting problem in statistical software...

Comment: Regarding the blog post linked in the original question, note #2: "Look for jargon that has meaning to the group of people you want to attract. Insider jargon is the duck call of insiders. Look at me! If I can say “contributory negligence,” I must be a real lawyer!"  This speaks to the reason that I think this is a poor name selection.

Comment: There's a Machine Learning proposal on Area 51 even though ML questions are part of the mission statement here.  I think the "Statistical Analysis" name keeps some people away.  We should go for a name that has meaning for both ML and Statistics folks to encourage more cross fertilization between the two areas.  CrossValidated seems pretty good to me for that reason.

Answer (score 12):

## ConfidenceRegion.com

(domain name available)

Comment: Not bad -- a place for giving people confidence by answering their questions, as well as the obvious statistical meaning.

Comment: Dig it.  It's not banal like StatsOverflow and should have meaning for the broad community of data analysts (statistics, machine learning, scientists, etc).  Come on folks, vote it up!

Comment: ... with a redirect from CredibleRegion.com for the Bayesians

Comment: I wasn't fast enough to submit some more: SampleSurveys - RepeatedMeasures - BackwardElimination - SignificanceLevel - OpinionPoll - NestedModels - MixedEffects - PurposiveSampling - AcceptanceSampling - InformativePriors - ConfoundingFactors - EfficientEstimates - DummyVariables - Contingency ..Tales :-)

Answer (score 11):

## CrossValidated.com

Comment: Would be good, if singular. That one however, seems to exist already

Comment: Right...hence the plural...alas!

Comment: CrossValidated.com is free.

Comment: @mbq: I like your variation (made the change).

Comment: I like this one the most at this point, because it not only covers a broadly applied technique, but also in some sense describes what we do on the site (i.e. have many different views on the same question to find the best solution).

Comment: I note that this is now registered by "Stack Overflow Internet Services, Inc."

Comment: Does Stack Overflow registering it mean that they've decided that is the name we are going to go with or is this still an open issue?

Comment: Still an open issue; they register names to protect them.

Comment: I downvoted this: it has no link to statistics for "outsiders", and as a statistician I don't get the "inside joke" feeling either. Cross-validation is a minor technique that is not that great either.

Comment: @Aniko: w.r.t. your point about the "inside joke", do you really think that everyone on stackoverflow.com knows what a stack overflow is?  I am quite sure that they don't given that Jeff Atwood previously admitted that he had no idea what it was.  I also don't entirely see how cross-validation is a minor technique; IMO, it's pretty fundamental, especially given the broad "data analysis" basis for the site.

Comment: How about giving it an Italian flavour: CrossValidate.it ?

Comment: @Shane I don't mean that the name should be understandable to both insiders and outsiders, but to at least one of these groups. I would think _real programmers_ would know what stackoverflow means (even I do, despite being only an amateur programmer)

Comment: @Aniko. Every data miner would know about cross-validation, and I think most statisticians would too, although perhaps not under that name. After all, it is closely related to the jack-knife, and to leverage in regression, and to studentized residuals. And it is widely used in nonparametric regression for bandwidth selection. I disagree that it is a minor technique.

Comment: So my 2 cents is that it isn't a name that jumps out to me as being related to statistics. I've heard of all of the other things Rob lists above, but never had I heard them referred to as cross-validation until I came here.  The litmis test for a name should be if you tell someone what the name is are they going to have a sense of what the site is about.  Things may be different for others, but in my area of study I doubt they'll instantly know what the site "CrossValidated.com" is for or about.

Comment: The wikipedia disambiguation page for "cross validation" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation) lists three meanings. Only one has anything to do with statistics, and that is a fairly narrow part of statistics. We can find a more general name.

Comment: @Harvey Two other meanings are marginal; still the point is somewhere else -- it connects statistics, machine learning and data mining, which are all legitimate topics of this site.

Comment: @(all that think one should be familiar with name to find/use the site) -- no, new users will find it by its contents, not name. As Shane mentioned stack overflow is a very specific error and is not commonly known, and still it makes no problem for SO. Also I don't think that median Windows user will now what superuser means.

Comment: @Harvey: That seems like a reach...did you look at the other ones listed?  Wikipedia has many disambiguation pages for familiar terms.  The statistical meaning is overwhelmingly the most common.  Just look at any of the results returned from a google search.

Comment: One other reason to choose "CrossValidated" over "StatsOverflow" is that it is amenable to a good logo (e.g. involving some picture like this: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_Hyi86mcXHNw/SKy-jwKHbDI/AAAAAAAAAOE/W4bViOnUoWA/s1600-h/Cross+Validation.png).

Comment: @mbq: Imagine the case of someone who hears about the site and its content, then several weeks later decided they want to visit the site.  When they try to remember the name of the site, a name that is meaningful and related to the content (in a way they understand) will be easier to remember than something they don't instantly recognize. Sure, many of them will find the source that mentioned the site and get here anyway - but some won't.  Also the infrequent users are somewhat less likely to come back - and more likely to get lost in their google search.

Comment: Just a random note on this point in general: Cross-validation seems like a procedure you can use in statistics, but despite claims it is analogous to certain fit statistics (e.g. AIC/BIC, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/577/is-there-any-reason-to-prefer-the-aic-or-bic-over-the-other), at least here, a demonstration of the way in which it is analogous is lacking (e.g. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/608/how-can-one-empirically-demonstrate-in-r-which-cross-validation-methods-the-aic-a).

Comment: drknexus - how is "StatsOverflow.com" any more memorable than "Crossvalidated.com"?  "Overflow" only has meaning for people who know about StackOverflow, who form a very small group - and a group that's likely to be able to find a statistics site in the StackOverflow family without needing to know what the name is.  Conversely, an advantage of CrossValidated is that it's clear about what kind of statistics are being talked about - it's clearly not sports/government/etc. statistics, it's analysis.

Comment: @drknexus I don't agree; people look for information, not tools. They will also probably mostly ask own question after founding here a similar question that still don't satisfy their need. About AIC/BIC -- read my comments on the topic, those equivalence theorems hold only in a narrow set of situations (mostly linear models).

Comment: I would hope this site would welcome scientists who need help with data analysis. To facilitate this, we shouldn't use jargon in the site name. 

What would happen if asked a bunch of scientists to identify the field in which "cross-validate" is used, and offered five choices:
 a)statistics,
 b)psychotherapy, 
 c)anthropology, 
 d)accounting, or
 e)comparative literature.

I suspect you'd end up with about 20% guessing each.

Comment: @Harvey: (1) I think that you're wrong about that survey; this concept is primarily associated with statistics/machine learning.  Again: just try a google search: all the top research relate to the right thing. (2) IMO, having jargon is a good thing, as per the blog post in the original question.  (3) If you have a better idea, please propose it; I would be happy to see a better name myself (I like CV in part because of its meta interpretation).  I see StatsOverflow as problematic both because it's "Stats" (hence not including other areas) and Overflow (which has nothing to do with us).

Comment: Note: we will be starting a new round of voting starting next Monday, only including the top choices.  That will be a good opportunity to lay out all the pros/cons of the different options.

Answer (score 8):

## StatsExchange.com

Comment: This seems to be a pretty under-rated option - but it is already reserved.

Answer (score 8):

## MaximumLikelihood.com

Answer (score 6):

## Overfitting.com

Comment: Or maybe ModelOverfit.com to stick to two-word standard?

Comment: read as Mode-Lover-Fit also :-P

Comment: @gd047 Good point.

Answer (score 6):

## DegreesofFreedom

Comment: I like this because it covers the data mining as well as the more traditional statistical side of the site. It also doesn't emphasise one area (e.g., Bayesian methods or hypothesis testing).

Comment: This domain name is "backordered".  Not sure what that means.

Comment: That it is not FreedomDegrees.

Answer (score 5):

## www.randomvariate.com

Comment: Or perhaps RandomVariable, since the word "Variate" is not widely known?

Comment: @Aniko, unfortunately RandomVariable.com is already owned by someone.

Answer (score 5):

AllYourBayes.com

If we don't want to appear partisan:

AllYourBayesAndFreqs.com

Comment: Don' we want something that also seems to include statistical programming and data visualization?

Answer (score 5):

## ModelConvergence.com

Answer (score 5):

## OptimumModel.com

Comment: I like this because a "model" is such a general term (used in all areas), and optimization is a very general goal.  Plus it has a meta-interpretation about our role on the site.

Answer (score 4):

## StatsFaq.com

I own this domain and would be happy to donate it. Nice and succinct, isn't it?

I also own the domains **StatFaq.com**, **StatFaqs.com** and **StatsFaqs.com** as forwarding addresses, so anyone who omits or adds an "s" would wind up at the right site.

Comment: I like the shortest variant, StatFaq.com, for the main domain to which the other variants should forward.

Comment: I prefer "stats" because it works as a shorthand for "statistics"; "StatFAQ" doesn't make as much sense to me. But if other people like it, I'd be fine with using it.

Answer (score 4):

## ModelOverfit.com

(available)
*Based on [this discussion](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21/what-should-our-site-be-called-what-should-our-domain-name-be/51#51)*

Answer (score 4):

### ExplanatoryVariable.com

Answer (score 3):

## EnsembleMethods.com

(available) This is a play on concept of [ensemble learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning):

> In statistics and machine learning,
> ensemble methods use multiple models
> to obtain better predictive
> performance than could be obtained
> from any of the constituent models.

Answer (score 2):

I listed a [few here in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5547/proposal-for-statistics-data-mining-stackexchange-site/5775#5775), but my favorite is "**Confidence Intervals**"; several of these are available as domain names.

Answer (score 2):

## alternativehypothesis.com

Comment: Although I like the connotation of "alternative" - as if we are providing alternative approaches for question askers, I down voted because I think this implies a focus on null hypothesis significance testing,

Answer (score 2):

## StatisticalSignificance.com

Comment: I think we should try to avoid names that lean towards specific branches of statistics. For example, StatisticalSignificance and NullHypothesis have a frequentist slant to them. A bad choice of name may put many people off the site.

Comment: We should also try to balance the data analysts/machine learning types who don't have any direct input in statistical debates.  It's a tough balancing act to please everyone!

Comment: OK! NullHypotheses it is then!

Answer (score 2):

### **Statosphere.com**

Comment: I've undeleted it because I liked it; I think we would be able to fetch this domain.

Answer (score 2):

## RandomPatterns.com

Answer (score 2):

## ExploratoryAnalysis.com

Answer (score 1):

PirateBayes.com

Comment: Arrrrrrrrrrr...

Comment: ThePirateBayes.com would be even better

Comment: @Veb absolutely.

Comment: @Shane more like [Rrrrrrrr](http://www.r-project.org)

Comment: Amusing, but not a reasonable candidate given that it connotes a narrow focus on bayesian statistics alone.

Comment: I am not for it - but it is funny :)

Answer (score 0):

damnlies.com doesn't seem to be doing much

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is Statistically Speaking, the .com of which is currently being parked for free by GoDaddy: http://www.statisticallyspeaking.com/

Comment: Note: "Parked for free" does not mean free.

Comment: The main problem with this (if it is a problem) is that it has statistics in the title, which could deter the machine learning community.  It also doesn't get across the idea of other forms of data analysis (e.g. visualization).

Answer (score -1):

How about www.normallydistributed.com ?

Comment: I don't love this because ideally our questions/answers will be fat tails (in terms of their degree of excellence).

Comment: When I saw this, the smart@ss in me really wanted to submit www.abnormallydistributed.com but the serious side of me slapped the smart@ss side into submission.  With that said and off of my chest, I agree with Shane.

Answer (score -1):

I thought of SignificanceTested. Domain is free, and it is in SE style.

Comment: Doesn't this implicitly exclude those who are not interested in significance tests per se?

Answer (score -1):

## NotIntractable.com

Answer (score -1):

MeanSquareErrors.com

Comment: Again, maybe singular?

Comment: Regretfully, that's unavailable...

Comment: I voted this down because I think it implies a focus on parametric statistics while neglecting the other domains of interest for this site.

Answer (score -1):

NullHypotheses.com

Comment: I like this but it would be better singular.

Comment: Unfortunately, the singular version is already taken unless we can do a ".net" instead of ".com".

Comment: I voted this down because I think it implies a focus on null hypothesis testing logic which is primarily relevant to the "statistics" focus of the site while neglecting the other domains of interest furthermore, not all people engaged in statistical inference are particularly happy with null hypothesis testing approaches.

Answer (score -1):

This one is available:

UnbiasedEstimates.com

Answer (score -1):

BootstrapConfidence.com

Answer (score -1):

infinitevariance.com

(Taken, but apparently for a personal site, so maybe the owner can be convinced to give it up.)

Answer (score -1):

Totally Stats!

## TotallyStats.com

Unambiguous. Easy to spell. Available.

Comment: Perfect! Easy to remember. Not confining.

Comment: I just think that this is TotallyUncreative and TotallyBoring...  :)  Otherwise, it's awesome.

Answer (score -1):

ModelEpiphany.com

Epiphany means:

> a sudden, intuitive perception of or
>   insight into the reality or essential
>   meaning of something

Comment: I see some Christmas connotations, but it looks ok.

Comment: I think of James Joyce in connection with this word (The Dubliners), but yes, it does have other connotations as well.

Answer (score -1):

## statistical-power.com

Apart from having interesting statistical meaning, it has positive connotations and is easy to use/understand.

Comment: No dash please!!

Answer (score -1):

OffTheMarkov.com

Comment: I like this one.  Good play on words.

Comment: Are the importance of Markov models general enough to encompass everything we want the site to cover?

Answer (score -1):

gaussinthehouse.com

Comment: Crazy, but I liked the rhythm.

Answer (score -1):

## liesanddamnlies.com

Comment: +1 I like this one, although it might be a little too much of an inside joke?

Comment: It's probably the least insidy of all the jokes here.  Mark Twain was pretty well known…

Comment: @Vebjorn: That's a fair point.

Comment: I don't like it because this kind of misconception is exactly what we're trying to eradicate.

Answer (score -1):

### marginoferror.com

Or, for the Car Guys fanciers:

margeinnovera.com

Answer (score -1):

StatsAnswers.com

Answer (score -1):

**DataAnalysisAnswers.com**

Answer (score -1):

## StandardDeviations.org

(.com is unavailable)

Answer (score -2):

## StatisticalInferences.com

Comment: I voted this down because I think it implies a focus on statistics and particularly statistical inference (as opposed to statistical prediction) while neglecting the other domains of interest for this site.

Answer (score -2):

statsOracle.net

Comment: I voted this down because I think it implies a focus on statistics while neglecting the other domains of interest for this site.

Answer (score -3):

markov-zorro.com

Answer (score -3):

**AllYourBayesAreBelongToUs**.com

A play on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_your_base_are_belong_to_us.

Comment: That's what my answer was playing on.  :)

Comment: Maybe not as the site name- but we could bring it out as a slogan or ad material once in a while.

Comment: Nice.  Your answer inspired mine, but I didn't realize that's what you had in mind!

Comment: @Sharpie: Good idea!  On our site tee-shirts.

Comment: Nice, but too long.

Comment: -1?  Really?  Oh boy...

Answer (score -4):

two-tailed-z.com