# Ideas and designs for posters

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Once we're out of beta, I'd like to announce the site at work.  There should be at least a few hundred potential users here.  Mass emailing is frowned upon, so I would like to hang posters by the elevators instead.

Does anyone have ideas for what to put on a poster?

Would anyone with design skills volunteer to make one?

The poster should be PDF and look good when printer on either letter-size or A4 paper.  Color is good, but it is nice if a black-and-white printout looks good as well.

Answer (score 4):

Idea lifted from [the site-name discussion](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21/what-should-our-site-be-called-what-should-our-domain-name-be/105#105):

**All your Bayes are belong to us**

Comment: +1 I, needless to say, love this idea.  Although it might be premature to having these kinds of discussions until the site name is determined?  You could also incorporate one of the xkcd comics from here (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423/what-is-your-favorite-data-analysis-cartoon) to get a little attention.

Comment: Didn't care for it as a site name, but it is an AWESOME poster slogan.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is useless to advertise something without a justified visual identification. On the other hand, beta is for testing, so some drawbacks that still exist may repel certain users.