# How to make second round of voting for the site name?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/489/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

### Note:

We are closing this domain naming thread. It is asking the *entirely* wrong question. See this blog post for details: [Domain Names: Wrong Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

We're going to keep the name ******************************webapps.stackexchange.com. But we WILL be setting up redirects from the more "popular" domains names (e.g. seasonedadvice.com to cooking.stackexchange.com, basicallymoney.com to money.stackexchange.com, and others as we go through the list).

New question: "**Write and Elevator Pitch / Tagline!**"

[**Click here to contribute ideas and vote.**](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/489/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

*[original message text below]*

---

Deadline is near (23rd), so we should decide what to do next. One proposal per answer, please.

*Edit*:

Just to note: we're currently having a discussion with the StackExchange team about conducting this as a blind poll.  Hoping to have an answer by tomorrow at which point we'll make a determination about the next step.

Answer (score 7):

I think that we should broaden the second round a little now that it's getting closer: maybe include the top 5 proposals?  Or take (anything) >= 0.5 * (the top proposal)?  Or anything >= the 75th percentile (of all proposals)?

I say the top 5 to keep it simple.  The rules on the second round should be:

1. No new proposals allowed (one of the moderators will post the top proposals)
2. No downvoting allowed (I prefer just having people up-vote)

I also think that we need to find a way to avoid massive numbers of comments and conflict, so maybe we should make an additional question where people can lay out their case for why a specific proposal is best/worst.  In this, I would encourage people to describe a possible logo (or site appearance) along with the proposal (some proposals may be more suitable than others for this).

Comment: +1: I like all of these ideas.  Top 5 for which domains are available sounds good.  I don't suppose there's any way for the system to prevent down votes?

Comment: This would be very possible with my idea. Everybody can: 1)  choose only one proposal, 2) not downvote, 3) not comment, 4) not add other names

Comment: @Peter: I see.  That would require different software.  I like the idea, but not sure that it's possible in the near future.  I'll ask on meta.so.

Comment: Top five sounds ok to me. I don't think we can prevent downvotes, but we can always just count upvotes. I like the idea of providing pros/cons for each proposal to help people in their voting.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest making this kind of blind poll (as done for the unix/ubuntu merge question) for the most popular names. Then let this run for a week and take the winner.

I have no doubt that we will come to a consensus on the logo and style. Especially because we will get an expert helping us if we get out of beta phase.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but could you explain what you mean by "blind poll"?

Comment: See for example http://unix.stackexchange.com/polls/2/should-unix-linux-and-ubuntu-merge. As far as I know you can not see the intermediate result.

Comment: I asked about this here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61966/blind-poll-questions

Answer (score 2):

Each proposal in the second round is a suggestion of a logo (sketch, description) for one of the names that were elected in the first round. Then voting as usual (with downvotes), best proposal win.
This way we wouldn't have a problem that we have a nice name but we can't agree on logo for it. And we would have the full identification ready.