# Site name selection

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-name

The [second round of voting on the site name is **now open**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/polls/2/what-should-our-domain-name-be).  This is a very important decision in the site's formation, so we appreciate everyone's contribution.  Keep the site's scope in mind as you make your decision:

> for statistical analysis, data mining,
>   machine learning, data visualization
>   and statistical computing

Also consider how the site name might be used for creating a logo and site design.

The poll will run for two weeks (until **September 21, 2010**).  Each person may vote up to three times (out of five name choices), but **all votes are final**, so be sure that you have given enough thought to your selections before voting.

Please use this question to outline any discussion points that you think would be relevant to this process.  We have listed each name below along with a description of their meaning.

### **[Click here to vote!](https://stats.stackexchange.com/polls/2/what-should-our-domain-name-be)**

You can find more background on this process in these additional questions:

- [What should our site be called? / What should our domain name be?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21/what-should-our-site-be-called-what-should-our-domain-name-be-closed)
- [How to make second round of voting for the site name?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357/how-to-make-second-round-of-voting-for-the-site-name)
- [Site name voting: decision time](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374/site-name-voting-decision-time)

Comment: I am posting the site names along with descriptions before we launch the poll (probably later today).  **Please do not vote on these answers!**

Comment: Perhaps, you should lock the answers.

Comment: I would rather not; I am happy for people to enhance these answers further as I just quickly threw them together.  **Please feel free to improve these descriptions!**

Comment: That makes sense to me.

Comment: Just to clarify, when it says "please vote in order of preference" does it mean *descending* order? ie first first, second second and third third?

Comment: @walkytalky: That's right.  Low scores are better (like in golf).

Comment: As a giant nerd, I would just like to say how glad I am that we're doing actual preferential votes.  Thanks to whomever made that happen (Shane?)

Comment: @Matt: It takes a village.  :)

Comment: Are we voting for a domain name? If so it will be hard to be both original and catchy.

Comment: @Thylacoleo yes we are voting for the domain name. See this link: http://stats.stackexchange.com/polls/2/what-should-our-domain-name-be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## crossvalidated.com

---

**Definition:** [Cross validation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) is a technique to guard against [overfitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) when optimizing a model, which involves using test and training subsets of data, and analyzing the same dataset repeatedly.

**Meta interpretation:** Our site allows the community to provide a range of answers and the best answer is then 'crossvalidated' by voting.

**Related stats questions:** [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1826/cross-validation-in-plain-english) [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2306/feature-selection-for-final-model-when-performing-cross-validation-in-machine-l)

**Logo idea (mbq):**

[image]

Comment: Downvoted to restore vote count to zero.

Answer (score 2):

## confidenceregion.com

---

**Definition:** In statistics, a [confidence region](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_region) is a multi-dimensional generalization of a [confidence interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval). It is a set of points in an n-dimensional space, often represented as an ellipsoid around a point which is an estimated solution to a problem. Model confidence is a measure of the reliability of an estimate.

**Meta interpretation:** You can be confident that our site will identify the best answer to your question.

**Related stats questions:** [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2272/whats-the-difference-between-a-confidence-interval-and-a-credible-interval) [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2220/how-do-we-create-a-confidence-interval-for-the-parameter-of-a-permutation-test) [3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1797/what-would-a-confidence-interval-around-a-predicted-value-from-a-mixed-effects-mo)

Comment: Please do not vote on these answers!! There is a separate poll running. (read question)

Comment: Downvoted to restore vote count to 0. Do not upvote or downvote.

Comment: Downvoted from 2 to 1 to help move the count back to 0 as it should be left, can someone please downvote once more to restore 0?

Comment: @Shane the link is 404

Answer (score 1):

## modelconvergence.com

---

**Definition:** In data analysis, a model typically represents a set of mathematical equations which describe the behavior of an object of study.  When the behavior is stochastic, the model may "converge" if a sequence of essentially random or unpredictable events settles into a pattern.  Convergence of an MCMC model also plays an important role in Bayesian statistics.

**Meta interpretation:** The community converges to the best answer to a question by voting up answers that are useful/correct and voting down answers that are not useful/correct.

**Related stats questions:** [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/507/what-is-the-best-method-for-checking-convergence-in-mcmc) [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2230/convergence-in-probability-vs-almost-sure-convergence)

Answer (score 0):

## degreesoffreedom.com

---

**Definition:** [Degrees of freedom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(statistics)) represents the number of values in a final calculation that are free to vary.

**Meta interpretation:** There are a large number of users that are free to provide different answers.

**Note:** The degreesoffreedom.com domain name is ***backordered***, which means that it may not be available right away.

**Related stats questions:** [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/884/what-are-degrees-of-freedom)

Answer (score 0):

## optimummodel.com

---

**Definition:** [Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_(mathematics)) is a general concept in mathematics, computer science, and data analysis which involves finding the best solution from all feasible solutions.

**Meta interpretation:** A question on our site is a "model" and our answers find the optimal solution.

Comment: Please do not vote on these answers!!  There is a separate poll running.

Comment: Upvoted to restore vote count to 0. Please do not upvote this further.

Answer (score 0):

**datareduction.com**

I have no idea whether it is too late to enter a name in the "competition", but the current entries don't quite do it for me. They are too specific. It seems that whether we are doing statistical analysis, data mining, machine learning, data visualization or statistical computing, what we are involved in is DATA REDUCTION, reducing the data deluge (datadeluge.com exists, http://www.datareduction.com/ is "for purchase") into meaningful summaries, whether mathematical or visual.

Comment: The time for suggestions has passed. We have now voted on the five top choices and the mods are still figuring out how to best interpret the votes. An announcement will be made shortly.