# Why is stats.stackexchange.com called Cross Validated, not Statistics Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, support, statistics, cross-validated

According to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) for "Cross Validation" :

> **Cross-validation**, sometimes called **rotation estimation** or **out-of-sample testing**, is any of various similar model validation techniques for assessing how the results of a statistical analysis will generalize to an independent data set. It is mainly used in settings where the goal is prediction, and one wants to estimate how accurately a predictive model will perform in practice. In a prediction problem, a model is usually given a dataset of known data on which training is run (training dataset), and a dataset of unknown data (or first seen data) against which the model is tested (called the validation dataset or testing set). The goal of cross-validation is to test the model's ability to predict new data that was not used in estimating it, in order to flag problems like overfitting or selection bias and to give an insight on how the model will generalize to an independent dataset (i.e., an unknown dataset, for instance from a real problem).

Clearly, Cross Validation is a statistical technique which is used to infer something about some data. As far as I know, there are thousands of such techniques or approaches which we use for solving different kind of problems relevant to statistics. Then, why is [stats.stackexhange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) is called ***Cross Validated*** ? Shouldn't it be called something like ***Statistics Stack Exchange***, just like the *Mathematics* one ?

I'm sorry if my question is silly, or had been answered previously. Thank you.

Comment: Here's how I interpret the name: You come here to validate your understanding of statistics through other statisticians. We cross link to other posts to build a network of improved understanding for future visitors of the site. It is vaguely, if at all related to the statistical concept of cross validated, but the goal is analogous. I see it as how a layman would interpret what crossvalidation might be.

Comment: Yeah cool. But that's true for any Stack Exchange site. Most of us come here, be it Math, Stat or CS, in order to validate our understanding of the subjects. So, by that logic, any of the networks could be named "Cross Validated". :P

Comment: Crossvalidation is a *statistical* technique. It wouldn't be a play on words for any of the other sites.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ten years ago, it was a custom that every site got its own name (i.e. Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault), not just *[topic]* Stack Exchange. There was a [community poll](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/412/79696) (sadly, the results are no longer visible) and Cross Validated was the winner.

Comment: I went through the link which you shared. Is it true that name "Statistics Stack Exchange" was never proposed for this site ? If so, I must say that I'll be quite surprised.